# WinCrt в Free Pascal и комбинированное движение

Tags: freepascal

```
uses WinGraph, WinCrt, WinMouse;

var gd,gm:SmallInt;
    ch: char;

Begin
    gd := Detect;
    gm := D8bit;
    InitGraph(gd,gm,'');
    UpdateGraph(UpdateOff);
    repeat
        ch := readkey;
        case ch of
            #0:
            Begin
                ch := readkey;
                case ch of
                    #72: writeln('up');
                    #80: writeln('down');
                    #75: writeln('left');
                    #77: writeln('right');
                end;
            end;
        end;
    until ch = #27;
    CloseGraph;
end.
```

Проблема данного кода в том, что нелья двигаться одновременно вверх и влево и тд., как это можно исправить?

Comment: Нужно обрабатывать события KEY_UP\KEY_DOWN но, я если честно понятия не имею как именно сделать это в DOS оболочке =)

Comment: Вот-вот, я с Pascal ABC перешел на Free Pascal, т.к. в колледже заставляют и теперь не знаю замену `KEY_UP\KEY_DOWN` А может знаете как убрать залипание? Когда начинаешь зажимать какую-то кнопку, он сначала медленно двигается, потом быстро.

Comment: Это не залипание а повтор, если одна клавиша зажата - система начинает генерировать "повторный" ввод символов, настраивается в свойтсвах клавиатуры(панель управление...)

Comment: Не, я в Pascal ABC мог сделать норм, чтобы сразу как жму вправо двигался вправо на макс скорости повторения нажатия кнопки

Comment: Вы разницу между событиями KEY_PRESS и KEY_DOWN не видите? второй срабатывает после того как клавиша нажата, а первый после 2х подряд идущих событий key_down+key_up, или если после события Key_down прошло X времени - начинают генерироваться повторы KEY_PRESS(Х - задается в настройках системы)